# Which of the following conditions / properties ensures that the $n\times n$ matrix $A$ is invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> **Question:** Which of the following conditions / properties ensure that the $n\times n$ matrix $A$ is invertible?
>
> **Possible answers:**
>
> 1. $A^T\cdot A$ is invertible
> 2. $A^T= A$
> 3. $A^2+ A + I = 0$
> 4. $AB=BA$, for any invertible matrix $B$

**My Answer:**
My answer is that number $1$ and $4$ are conditions that ensure that $n\times n$ matrix $A$ is invertible. Am I correct?

Comment: @Suraj You should probably give your response in an answer instead of comments

Comment: so 3 is the only conditions that ensures that n*n matrix A is invertible

Comment: @anders Both $(1),(3)$ ensure the invertibility of $A$

Comment: oh okey. thank you so much

Comment: $(1)$ is true, as $\det(A^TA)=\det(A^T)\cdot\det(A)=\det(A)^2\ne0\implies\det(A)\ne0$.

Comment: In order for (1) to be valid, $A$ needs to be a matrix whose entries are real numbers

Answer (score 1):

$1$- It implies $A$ is invertible because if we assume $|A|=m$ then because $A^{T}A$ is invertible then $m^2 \neq 0$ and hence  $|A|=m \neq0$ and Hence $A$ is invertible.

for $2$ and $4$ Consider $A=0$

$3$- consider $A\cdot(-A-I)=(-A-I)\cdot A=-A^2-A=I$. Hence $A$ is invertible in this case.

Thus only $1$ and $3$ implies $A$ is invertible

Comment: thank you so much for the help